# css layout not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, layout

I have an application which I am trying to layout. Everything is fine apart from the left column content. It should display *100% of the height* of the parent container, the same height as the right column.

`#Container` is the outer container.
`#TreeList` is the left column.
`#Tabcontrol` is the right column.

This is what my app looks like right now:

[image]

And here is the current css for my app:

```
html {
    font-family: Open Sans, Calibri, Arial;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 1500px;
}

body {

}

#Container {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid black;
}

#TreeList {
    position:relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #707070;
    border-top: 1px solid #707070;
    border-left: 1px solid #707070;
    float:left; 
    overflow:hidden;
    padding: 20px;

}

#TabControl {
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #707070;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left; 
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set any `height` in your css document, therefore all of the heights are pretty much random. First off set a main height for your `body` & `html` and then for the `container` like so:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#Container {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Then for your other elements:

```
#TreeList {
    position:relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #707070;
    border-top: 1px solid #707070;
    border-left: 1px solid #707070;
    float:left; 
    overflow:hidden;
    padding: 20px;
    height:100%;
}

#TabControl {
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #707070;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left; 
    padding: 20px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Or if you prefer you could use `position: absolute;` for your child element and do something like this:

```
child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Which will make the elements stretch to the entire screen and keep a width *you* choose.

This should work, although I highly recommend using Javascript to set the height for `body` as well as `position: absolute;` instead of `relative`;

Answer (score 1):

`height: 100%;` does not work like some would expect, you need a given height (em,%,px,etc..) on the parent element. In this case Your `body` I suppose. Add this to your css:

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
```

If you need a flexible parent container height there are several workarounds to achive that:

### #1 [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

You might take a look here: [Flexbox Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), works pretty neat, with the downside of [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

### #2 Absolute positioning

Give the parent `position: relative;` And your element `position: absolute; top: 0, bottom: 0; left: 0;` for example.

### #3 jQuery Plugin: [matchHeight](http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/)

This plugin does the job as well: [matchHeight](http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/), only requires jQuery included and javascript to run

Comment: doesnt work unfortunatly, tried it but nothing changes

Comment: <html>
<body>
<div container>
<div left column>
</div>
<div right column>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: In that case your `#container` does need a height as well.

Comment: tried all kinds of combinations of height on all parent containers, nothing affects the two columns

Answer (score 0):

Add 100% height to the left column.

```
 #TreeList { height:100% }
```

Comment: already tried that, as it was the obvious thing to do, still no luck